# como selecionar count igual a zero

Tags: sql, group-by

tenho essas tabelas (exemplo)

```
Municipio (id, nome)
1, Santos
2, Sao Paulo
3, Rio de Janeiro
4, Florianopolis
5, Porto Alegre
6, Natal

Cliente (id, nomecliente, cidade)
1, Joao, 1
2, Pedro, 3
3, Maria, 3
4, Julio, 3
5, Mario, 1
```

preciso fazer uma contagem de todos os municipios que tem zero clientes cadastrados
eu executei o codigo abaixo e iria só ordenar por numero de clientes, mas as cidades com clientes = 0 ele nao mostra no retorno, como faço para mostrar?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), cidade FROM cliente GROUP BY cidade
```

Comment: Qual o `SGBD` utilizado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você deve buscar os dados principais da tabela `municipio` para garantir que alguma linha irá retornar. Depois disso faça o vínculo com `LEFT JOIN` na tabela `cliente` e então realize o `COUNT` baseado na coluna `cliente.id` assim a contagem 0 será mostrada caso não haja nenhum cliente. Para filtrar usando o resultado de uma função de agregação, utilize a cláusula `HAVING`:

```
SELECT m.nome,
       COUNT(c.id) AS quantidade
  FROM municipio m
  LEFT JOIN cliente c ON c.cidade = m.id
 GROUP BY m.nome
HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 0
```

Resultando em:

```
| nome          | quantidade |
| ------------- | ---------- |
| Florianopolis | 0          |
| Natal         | 0          |
| Porto Alegre  | 0          |
| Sao Paulo     | 0          |
```

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tdbJ6TrfJ4kHk8gB17ZnJo/0).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a clausula `NOT EXISTS` para fazer isso. Assim:

```
SELECT 
mun.id, mun.nome
FROM municipio as mun
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT cidade FROM cliente WHERE cidade = mun.id
)
```

[veja funcionando](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8557d6/5)

E se você quiser o TOTAL. Ou seja a quantidade de cidades deste resultado, você pode fazer isso:

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM 
( 
    SELECT mun.id, mun.nome
    FROM municipio as mun
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT cidade FROM cliente WHERE cidade = mun.id
    )
) as sub;
```

[veja funcionando](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8557d6/6)

Comment: @Sorack valeu! Editei!

Answer (score 1):

Experimente desta forma (em *SQL Server*):

```
SELECT      M.nome                  AS municipio
        ,   ISNULL(C.clientes, 0)   AS clientes
FROM        Municipio   M
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      cidade
                        ,   COUNT(1) AS clientes
                FROM        Cliente
                GROUP BY    cidade
            )           C ON C.cidade = M.id
```

Assim ele devolve o total de clientes associados a municípios.

Se pretender apenas aqueles municípios com **0** cidades, então bastaria colocar uma cláusula `WHERE`:

```
WHERE ISNULL(C.clientes, 0) = 0
```

Em *MySQL* o `ISNULL` teria de ser substituído por `IFNULL`:

```
IFNULL(C.clientes, 0)
```

Comment: Duas vezes? Onde viu a 2ª?

Comment: `ISNULL` depende do SGBD

Comment: Sim, eu sei @Sorack, parti do princípio que fosse SQL Server.

Comment: Resposta editada com adição do `ISNULL` para MySQL.

Comment: Não? Mas a query corre sem problemas. Está-se a referir ao não devolver apenas cidades sem clientes?

Comment: Certo, na minha resposta referi exatamente isso! Para lhe devolver apenas cidades sem clientes terá que acrescentar a cláusula `WHERE` no fim: `WHERE IFNULL(C.clientes, 0) = 0`

Comment: @JoãoMartins ah ta... teria que usar a clausula where ... entendi...

Comment: @JoãoMartins deu certo > http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8557d6/25 =)

Comment: Aproveite e dê um UP nas respostas que considerou válidas e marque uma delas como correta :). [Porque é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Esquece @AndreiCoelho, vi mal! É 6ª feira, cansaço acumulado!

Comment: @JoãoMartins kkkkkk tranquilo!